# Gradle: Consuming a Zip artifact from an included build

Tags: gradle

I have a project producing a zip file and another project consuming the latter. It must be working somehow, in a similar way as below, however, I couldn't make it yet. Neither I really understand how dependencies are wired together through included builds only.

This is what I tried:

*zip-producing-project/settings.gradle:*

```
rootProject.name = 'zip-producing-project'
```

*zip-producing-project/build.gradle:*

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

task createZip(type: Zip) {
    from 'src/main/resources'
    include '*'
    archiveName 'zip-producing-project.zip'
}

artifacts {
    archives file('build/distributions/zip-producing-project.zip') // not sure "archives" is the right configuration
}

tasks.build.dependsOn "createZip"
```

*zip-consuming-project/settings.gradle:*

```
rootProject.name = 'zip-consuming-project'
includeBuild '../zip-producing-project'
```

*zip-consuming-project/build.gradle:*

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    archives 'org.example:zip-producing-project:1.0-SNAPSHOT@zip' // is that correct?
}

task unzip(type: Copy) {

    configurations.archives.resolve().forEach {
        if (it.name.endsWith(".zip")) {
            from zipTree(it)
        }
    }

    into "${project.buildDir}"
}
```

Calling `gradle clean build` yields:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'zip-consuming-project\build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'zip-consuming-project'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':archives'.
   > Could not find zip-producing-project.zip (project :zip-producing-project)
```

How do I make it work, i. e. make `zip-consuming-project` find the artifact `zip-producing-project.zip`?

Answer (score 0):

*I found a workaround, but I'm not happy with it.*

Included build (publisher):

```kotlin
artifacts {
    add("archives", tasks.register<Zip>("publishSomething") {
        archiveClassifier.set("something")
        from(...)
    })
}
```

Including build (consumer)

```kotlin
val extractSomething = tasks.register<Copy>("extractSomething") {
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("included-name").task(":publishSomething"))
    // This is the hacky part, ideally this would be simply `from(gradle.iB().t())`
    from(zipTree(rootProject.file("some/included-name/build/distributions/included-name-something.zip")))
    into(layout.buildDirectory.dir("extracted-something"))
}
tasks.named("compileKotlin").configure { dependsOn(extractSomething) }
```